# How do i disable the Windows 11 Touch (NOT Trackpad) gestures without disabling getting Touchinputs?

Tags: touch-event, windows-11

I have the problem with my Application on windows, that takes Wintouch as input and when i use more then two fingers, windows start to make a dropdown (like pressing win + d) and minimisses the window.

I want to disable this without loosing touch completely.
i thought something like Edge-UI could be this, but i dont fine it on win11.

OS Name Microsoft Windows 11 Home the newest Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621.

Mit freundlichen Grüßen,
John L.

I tryed to find the edge-UI without any succsess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem.

win11 seems to do it all over the settings menu and i found it on:
settings > bluetooth & devices > touch > three- and four finger  touch gestures -> disable

This fixed the issue that windows-11 minimises multitouch applications!

mfg.